# Specify client port Node js request

Tags: node.js, http

Sending a request from NodeJs, I want to specify the starting port, for example:

request to google.com port 80

from port 52000.

So the connection will be from from port 52000 to 80. 
My goal is to bootstrap a web server under a NAT, but I'm not allowed to set the forwarding port on the NAT itself.

How can I perform it?
 Thank you!!

Comment: this might help u https://stackoverflow.com/a/31665053/9020340

Comment: That topic is about specifying the target port, I want to set the port of the client request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [official node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener) (which I advise you to check), you have a `localAddress` and `localPort` properties, which you can use to bind to them before connecting to a remote socket.

That's the lowest level. Node HTTP requests expose the socket, so you can use it to access those properties, or you can write your own HTTP requester with basic nodejs sockets.